# how to set cron through php for every 5 mins

Tags: php, cron

step1:crontab -![e
no crontab for rizwan - using an empty one
888](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rxOj.png)

vi test

05 * * * * php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/mg2ERP_customers_create.php

after entering the path for saving i used as ctrl+z but,after for checking cronfiles i typed as crontab -l it shows no crontab for rizwan,if anyone knows please comment here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: */5 * * * * php xxxxxx

Comment: i have to run a  php file for every 5 mins,(for that am using cron),how to set cron for my php file.

Comment: I was running a php file,its works good manually,but i want to run this php file every 5 mins automatically,how to do this task,please help ?,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below Steps:

1) To add the required cronjob in crontab use below command:

crontab -e

2) Now add the cronjob using below command:

05 * * * * php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/mg2ERP_customers_create.php

3) To save

Press Escape

Type :wq!

Press enter

4) To see the added cronjob use below command:

crontab -l

Comment: Dear amarjeet Thanks for u r immediate response,i already tried this one ,but it not works for me.

Comment: 1) To add the required cronjob in crontab use below command:
crontab -e  ,it display like that ........no crontab for rizwan - using an empty one
888  then i added the command 05 * * * * php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/mg2ERP_customers_create.php

Comment: 2.for saving while Pressing escape it prints as ^[

Comment: What you are doing to save the entry. Did you try using - Press Escape and type :wq! and then press enter ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can any one respond to this question pls ?

Comment: Add a >>/tmp/testlog.log to the end of your crontab entry (to redirect output to a file you can investigate or check if it's running, additionally a 2>&1 would include output from the error console)

Comment: 05 * * * * php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/mg2ERP_customers_create.php >>/tmp/testlog.log